# Table tags for form display are bad... but what about survey questions like rt type?

Tags: css, layout, html-table, survey

[Is it bad design to use table tags when displaying forms in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109488/is-it-bad-design-to-use-table-tags-when-displaying-forms-in-html)

The accepted answer to this question in short: YES...

...but what about something like this:

[image]

I can't really think of different & better solution. The example is from SurveyMonkey and uses tables too.

**Is it still bad design to use table tags for such likert type questions?**

Comment: table tags for form display never were bad if you had asked me. what was bad was to stuff one table into another table into another table into another table into another table into another table into another table into another table into another table into another table just to "layout" a website. actually table based designs are coming back with CSS even, they just don't use table tags, only table rendering (which was not possible with HTML 3.2, hence tables were used a bit too much that time).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This type of question leads more to opinions than to hard and fast facts, but I would say that in this case it's definitely OK to use tables -- you're wanting a tabular display of information.

Just use the table tag and don't let people make you feel guilty for it  :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's not bad to use tables per se. It's just bad to use them to layout your entire site using infinitely nested tables and invisible images for space.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very hard with some help.
You might look into some of the grid-based css libraries our there.
[Yahoo Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)
[Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)
[960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

Comment: and if I do it with tables, is it bad design, and if yes, why?

Comment: If you use the table correctly (set ths correctly, make it readable for a screen reader, etc), then there's no problem here.  It's a table of selectable options, so it's appropriate to use a table.
I was just trying to give you another mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

What everyone says is "you should only use tables for tabular data". So ... what does that mean?

Here's my criterion for when something actually is tabular data: when you can only know what something is/does by reference to its *coordinates*, its position in relation to column and row headers.

So, in the case above, what is the function of the ninth radio button?

There's no way of knowing what it is unless you look left to the kind of skill it refers to and look up to the kind of level you're claiming. Therefore, this is tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of accessibility, IMHO, it would make more sense laid out as a table, with appropriate th tags etc.  As Ambrose said, the coordinates of the radio buttons give them contextual meaning.

You could lay it out without a table, and maybe make sense of it using labels, titles and other devices, but the only thing you would really achieve would be to demonstrate your css-fu.