# Complicated form table vs div

Tags: html, css, forms, tablelayout

I looked online for examples of implementation of the form using DIVs and all I see is pretty simple one column forms. I have some pretty complicated forms, here is a picture of one:

http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/8292/formn.jpg

It is easy to make it work with table (which I do), the only problem I have is that sometimes **I need to not display some of the choices and move the values up one row to avoid gaps**.

I started making some forms using divs, but they fall apart when I change the browser window size and it is not easy to align things.

This topic is helpful: 
[Is it bad design to use table tags when displaying forms in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109488/is-it-bad-design-to-use-table-tags-when-displaying-forms-in-html)
but it doesn't address some of the concerns I have.

What would you propose as a solution? I can dynamically delete/insert values in the table or try to do the DIVs.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I need it to work in IE6-7, that adds some complexity as well with gimmicky min-width and other IE bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go the div route.  As long as you're careful of your widths when you apply floats, it's actually pretty straightforward to get the layouts to work properly in different screen resolutions.

Here are a few rules:

1. Set a max width on your form or your form's wrapper element.  If you want to float elements on one row make sure their width's added together does not exceed this width.
2. If you are adding horizontal padding/margins to your floated elements remember that these add to the total width of the element.
3. Avoid mixing percentage widths with pixel padding and margins.  Apply the percentage width to a parent element and the pixel padding/margins to a child element.
4. Use clearing elements between your rows of elements to keep everything in line.

As to the markup, you can use the form elements along with CSS to create a semantic structure:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Fieldset Title</legend>

    <label for="input1">Input 1:</label>
    <span><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1"/></span>
    <label for="input2">Input 2:</label>
    <span><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2"/></span>

    <br/>

    <label for="input3">Input 3:</label>
    <span><input type="text" id="input3" name="input3"/></span>
    <label for="input4">Input 4:</label>
    <span><input type="text" id="input4" name="input4"/></span>
</fieldset>
```

And the CSS:

```
fieldset {
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

legend {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

label, span{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

input {
    width: 120px;  
}

br {
    clear: both;  
}
```

You can [see the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/hhUGk/).

Comment: There is one issue with this solution - I have several such search forms and I display the search field dynamically and that creates gaps when I don't display one of the fields and that is the main problem I am trying to solve.
Your solution won't move the fields up if I skip one of the fields.

Comment: @Romario Do you mean that if you don't show a field in a column, the fields below don't move up to fill the gap?

Comment: Then you'll need to adjust the code so that you have 2 floated columns side by side in the `<fieldset>`.  Adds 2 extra markup containers, but it will give you the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hhUGk/1/

Answer (score 1):

If it is a fixed-width table, it's trivial to lay out with divs and floats. Just set each width to exactly what you want.

For a liquid-layout table—and liquid layout is in general highly desirable—it is much harder to arrange a form without table-style-display, because `float` and `position` do not readily allow for calculations like “this cell is half the remaining width of the parent, after the fixed-width labels have been allocated”.

So in cases like this, which certainly includes the kind of two-column form you posted, the `table-*` CSS `display` values are your only possibility. If you are aiming only at IE8 and the other modern browsers, you can use divs and set `display: table-row` et al in the stylesheet. However for compatibility with IE6-7 and other older/mobile/niche browsers, you will have to use actual `<table>`/`<tr>`/`<td>` elements, as only the modern browsers support table-CSS independently of the table-elements.

There is no shame in this. A form is kind-of semi-tabular anyway and there is no practical accessibility disadvantage because the page content remains ordered appropriately.

Note: for liquid-layout forms you also have the issue of sizing input fields to match the parent element. `input { width: 100%; }` almost does it, but not quite, because the `width` is not including the border or padding that inputs get by default. You can use CSS3 `box-sizing` and the browser-specific versions of it to get around that for modern browsers, but if you want it to line up exactly to the pixel on IE6-7 too you would have to use padding on the parent elements equal to the border/padding on the child input field.

Answer (score 0):

- `General information` is some kind of list, key > value list to be exact - `<dl />` would be probably the best structure for it
- `Issues values` is a table,
- `Ratings` is a table,
- Both `Redemption` and `Indicators` are lists - unordered lists `<ul />`